# Free-flow Alternative to Powerpoint?

Tags: software-rec, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, slideshow, mind-mapping

So I've been digging around the net trying to find a good set of alternatives to Powerpoint.  Part of my interest is that I found one, [Prezi](http://www.prezi.com/), that I liked for it's free-form style.  Part of the power of it was that I can zoom out and select any part of the presentation to continue from and it feels much like a [mind map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map) or association of thoughts.

Are there any other tools that offer anything similar in vein to this way of presenting material?  I'm looking for something that just pops differently than a death-by-powerpoint-style presentation, so I would be happy to find tools that help present information in more fluid styles.

It doesn't have to mirror Prezi, and I wouldn't want that, but after seeing what Prezi does, I have to think there are other ways of presenting information to a group of people than one square slide at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe check out [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

One worth looking into is [JessyInk](http://code.google.com/p/jessyink/). It can be run in "march of slides" style, and tutorials seem to assume that's what you want to do, but it is possible to get it to work more like Prezi, or something in between.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office Labs released [pptPlex](http://www.officelabs.com/projects/pptPlex/Pages/default.aspx), which is like Prezi but for PowerPoint.  While no longer maintained, it still works and may give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use LibreOffice Writer (!) to create presentations and [impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/index.php) for showing them. I find it much more comfortable to make presentations in LibreOffice Writer than in LibreOffice Impress. For dmath addon doesn't work in impress. And also other stuff, like making tables - are much more developed in Writer then in Impress. Just make a paper to be of 28x21 cm, and don't forget to use styles!

Answer (score -1):

Try one of these

- Open Office
- Google Docs

Comment: Neither of those has the freeform capabilities requested by Nick.

Comment: I think I wrongly read the question as "Free alternatives to PowerPoint". Very much sorry about it. :(